# Saving the same form with different data using ajax and python.

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

Question I want to save the same form with ajax but, my form can be in multiples basically if they click on a button it presents them with my dim form, so how ever many times they click the button the dim form will appear. Example below I want to add two dims to my database so I am presented with two dim forms. Saving the first one works but, on the second the data I submit is the same as the first one. I tried keying off name instead of id with no luck I tried serializing the data no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

here is SaveDim function

```
function SaveDim() { 
    var dim_form = $("#dim_form :input") 
    .filter(function (index, element) { 
        return $(element).val() != ""; 
    }) 
    .serialize(); 
    alert(dim_form); 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "/sheet/sheet_form_create.html/_dim", 
        //dataType: "json", 
        data: 
            + 
            "&description=" + $('#id_description').val() + 
            "&style=" + $('#id_style').val() + 
            "&target=" + $('#id_target').val() + 
            "&upper_limit=" + $('#id_upper_limit').val() + 
            "&lower_limit=" + $('#id_lower_limit').val() + 
            "&inspection_tool=" + $('#id_inspection_tool').val() + 
            "&critical=" + $('#id_critical').val() + 
            "&units=" + $('#id_units').val() + 
            "&metric=" + $('#id_metric').val() + 
            "&target_strings=" + $('#id_target_strings').val() + 
            "&ref_dim_id=" + $('#id_ref_dim_id').val() + 
            "&nested_number=" + $('#id_nested_number').val() + 
            "&posistion=" + $('#id_position').val() + 
            "&met_upper=" + $('#id_met_upper').val() + 
            "&met_lower=" + $('#id_met_lower').val() + 
            "&valc=" + $('#id_valc').val() + 
            "&sheet_id=" + $('#id_sheet_id').val() + 
            "", 
        success: function (json) { 
            console.log(json); 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

and here is my _dim view

```
% load crispy_forms_tags %} 




<br /> 
<br /> 
<br /> 


<div class="my-Dim" > 
    <form id="dim_form" method="POST" action=""> {% csrf_token %} 
      {% crispy dim_form %} 
      <button class="updatedim" onclick="SaveDim()">Save Dim</button> 
    </form> 
</div> 
<div id="output"></div>
```

Here is my python method

```
def add_dimensions(request): 
  if request.method == 'POST': 
    c_date = datetime.now() 
    u_date = datetime.now() 
    description = request.POST.get('description') 
    style = request.POST.get('style') 
    target = request.POST.get('target') 
    upper_limit = request.POST.get('upper_limit') 
    lower_limit = request.POST.get('lower_limit') 
    inspection_tool = request.POST.get('inspection_tool') 
    critical = request.POST.get('critical') 
    units = request.POST.get('units') 
    metric = request.POST.get('metric') 
    target_strings = request.POST.get('target_strings') 
    ref_dim_id = request.POST.get('ref_dim_id') 
    nested_number = request.POST.get('nested_number') 
    met_upper = request.POST.get('met_upper') 
    met_lower = request.POST.get('met_lower') 
    valc = request.POST.get('valc') 
    sheet_id = request.POST.get('sheet_id') 
    data = {} 
    dim = Dimension.objects.create( 
          description=description, 
          style=style, 
          target=target, 
          upper_limit=upper_limit, 
          lower_limit=lower_limit, 
          inspection_tool=inspection_tool, 
          critical=critical, 
          units=units, 
          metric=metric, 
          target_strings=target_strings, 
          ref_dim_id=ref_dim_id, 
          nested_number=nested_number, 
          met_upper=met_upper, 
          met_lower=met_lower, 
          valc=valc, 
          sheet_id=sheet_id, 
          created_at=c_date, 
          updated_at=u_date) 
    data['description'] = dim.description; 
    data['style'] = dim.style; 
    data['target'] = dim.target; 
    data['upper_limit'] = dim.upper_limit; 
    data['lower_limit'] = dim.lower_limit; 
    data['inspection_tool'] = dim.inspection_tool; 
    data['critical'] = dim.critical; 
    data['units'] = dim.units; 
    data['metric'] = dim.metric; 
    data['target_strings'] = dim.target_strings; 
    data['ref_dim_id'] = dim.ref_dim_id; 
    data['nested_number'] = dim.nested_number; 
    data['met_upper'] = dim.met_upper; 
    data['met_lower'] = dim.met_lower; 
    data['valc'] = dim.valc; 
    data['sheet_id'] = dim.sheet_id; 
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json",) 

  else: 
      dim_form = DimForm() 
      return render(request, 'app/_dim.html', {'dim_form': dim_form})
```

## screen shot for better explanation

[image]

Comment: Whenever you insert a new form, you have to increment the names with a variable, so that all the names aren't the same. Then give the forms a class, and use `$('.forms').serialize()` to get **all** the data, no need for lengthy strings.

Comment: Can you give me and example @adeneo

Comment: Not really, as it's not clear how these forms are inserted, but it should be easy to implenent, just count the number of forms currently on the page, and increment a number before, after, or somewhere in the names of the form inputs etc.